Route parameter typing error with TypeScript and unplugin-vue-router
I'm learning Vue 3 with the Composition API using TypeScript. One of the tutorials I'm doing suggests using unplugin-vue-router to autogenerate routes based on file naming/path conventions. The plugin works correctly, but TypeScript is upset about route parameters. For example, I have this basic Vue page:
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
const route = useRoute()
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Page slug: {{ route.params?.slug }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

TypeScript is highlighting slug and warning that "Property 'slug' does not exist on type 'Record<never, never> | { catchAll: string; } | { slug: string; } | { id: string; }'."

Doing some Googling, I found this exact problem as an issue on the unplugin-vue-router Github site, but the suggestion to "use type narrowing" is vague and doesn't really work in this situation, as far as I can tell.
How can I get rid of this TypeScript error when using route parameters and unplugin-vue-router?

The suggestion is saying you need to inspect the shape of params because it may not be an object with a slug property. Try {{ ("slug" in route.params && route.params.slug) }}

You can provide a type to useRoute like this:
const route = useRoute<'ProductDetails'>()

The type for 'ProductDetails' comes from the RouteNamedMap provided by unplugin-vue-router:
'ProductDetails': RouteRecordInfo<'ProductDetails', '/products/:id', { id: ParamValue<true> }, { id: ParamValue<false> }>,

However, this approach may currently result in the following TypeScript error:
Type '"ProductDetails"' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof RouteNamedMap'.
Attending to the documentation you can find:
// these are all valid
let userWithId = useRoute() as RouteLocationNormalizedLoaded<'/users/[id]'>
userWithId = useRoute<'/users/[id]'>()
//  this one is the easiest to write because it autocompletes
userWithId = useRoute('/users/[id]')

userWithId.params

So there might be one for you.

The easiest was userWithId = useRoute('/users/[id]') which works fine, though it seems a bit counter-intuitive to have to specify the route when the whole point of unplugin-vue-router is to make routing dynamic based on conventions. Thanks!
